# program to exclude number having apart from 1,2,3

Tags: java, regex, lambda, regex-group

I am just practicing some coding questions I got question definition like

> Given an array of numbers, the task is to print only those numbers which have only 1, 2 and 3 as their digits.

for that I have code written like this

```
public class PrintArrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintArrays p = new PrintArrays();
        List<Integer> list =    p.findNumbers(new int[]{22,123,456,145,5,3,000,10,453});
        String s = new String("23");
        list.forEach(data -> System.out.println(data));
    }

    private List<Integer> findNumbers(int[] is) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        Arrays.stream(is)
                .filter(data -> !String.valueOf(data)
                .matches("(0|[a-zA-Z4-9].*)"))//tried to match if it contains  alphabets or any other number apart from 1,2,3
                .sorted()
                .forEach(data -> list
                .add(data));
        return list;
    }
}
```

my desire output is

```
3
22
123
```

What I got :

```
3
10
22
123
145
```

please help me to improve my regex

Comment: Why are you matching negatively? It's much easier to make a regex to find positives here.

Comment: I did first what I got in my mind, ya it's easy by your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just replace :

```
.filter(data -> !String.valueOf(data).matches("(0|[a-zA-Z4-9].*)"))
```

with

```
.filter(data -> String.valueOf(data).matches("[123]+"))
```

I makes two changes removed the not operator `!` and used this regex `[123]+` which match one or more digit in the class `[123]`

**Outputs**

```
3
22
123
```

Comment: ya it worked.but can you please help me to improve regex I gave? just curious to identify my problem

Comment: @LowCool The question is, What your regex should match ?

Comment: @LowCool It's difficult to tell what that regex is trying to do. It matches anything that starts with a `0` or anything in `[a-zA-Z4-9]` followed by any number of any characters.

Comment: I just wanted try by grouping so I added like if it contains 0 or that other part

Comment: I really don't get you @LowCool can you edit your question and describe your problem more than this!

Comment: I added please see once

Comment: what did you add @LowCool?

Comment: comment on my code where I am matching regex let me know if it make sense

Comment: @LowCool to do that you can use `"[a-zA-Z04-9]+"` this will **match if it contains  alphabets or any other number apart from 1,2,3**, hope this can help you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162720/discussion-between-lowcool-and-ycf-l).

Comment: @LowCool I'm sorry, I can't use chat in my company, I'm sorry, If you have a question you can put it as a comment

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use regex to complete the task - a simple loop enumerating the digits of an `int` would be sufficient:

```
static boolean is123(int x) {
    if (x == 0) {    // Treat zero as a special case
        return false;
    }
    while (x != 0) { // Divide by ten until we get to zero
        if (x%10 < 1 || x%10 > 3) {
            // If we get a digit other than 1, 2, or 3, return false
            return false;
        }
        x /= 10;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Here is how to use it for filtering numbers:

```
List<Integer> result = Arrays.stream(is)
    .filter(Test::is123) // Test is the name of the class enclosing is123 method
    .sorted()
    .boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/MetL4p)